# How do I stop pod2html from treating "=head2 open() foo" as a function definition?

Tags: perl, perl-pod

I have some POD that looks like

```
=head2 C<close() on unopened filehandle %s>

=over

=item C<Yer tryna close() %s what ain't been opened yet>

=back
```

The `pod2html` command turns it into

```
<h2><a name="close____on_unopened_filehandle__s"><a href="#item_close"><code>close () on unopened filehandle %s</code></a></a></h2>
<dl>
<dt><strong><a name="item_close"><code>Yer tryna close() %s what ain't been opened yet</code></a></strong>

</dl>
```

The problem is `<a href="#item_close"></a>`.  I am assuming it is doing this to be helpful (in the common case where `=item func()` is the start of a function definition), but it is inappropriate in my case (it is a warning message).

I have tried (with no success) the following to make pod2html not see `=item open()` as a function definition:

```
=head2 C<closeZ<>() on unopened filehandle %s>

=head2 C<closeE<40>) on unopened filehandle %s>

=head2 C<closeE<0x28>) on unopened filehandle %s>
```

The last two don't print "(".  Am I using E<> incorrectly?  Is this a bug in pod2html (I am using Perl 5.8.8 on OS X)?

Based on a thought brian's answer sparked I tried another experiment:

```
=head2 C<closeE<60>) on unopened filehandle %s>
```

Which should have resulted in `<code>close<) on unopened filehandle %s</code>`, but it produced `<code>close) on unopened filehandle %s</code>` instead.  So it looks like `pod2html` doesn't like numeric entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Pod::Html doesn't like numeric entities inside of `C<>` even though `perldoc` has no problem with them.  If I take the `C<>` off

```
=head2 closeE<40>) on unopened filehandle %s
```

it works just fine (and prevents `pod2html` from creating the spurious link).  So the answer seems to be to not use `C<>` here.

Comment: Well, the =head processing is different than the =item processing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of pod2html and Pod::Html (or whatever your pod2html loads) are you using? The one I have on my Mac is Pod::Html 1.0504 and will always try to make the link on the first instance of the text it sees in an =item. Remember, you can always look at the source to see why it's doing something :)

And, I'd avoid using C<> in headings. Let the processor figure out how to display those.

If you want nested interior sequences, you can add more angle brackets to make it easier to recognize:

```
C<< closeE<40> >>
```

Despite all of that, I recommend you use the format of perldiag, which doesn't do anything special with the open paren in an item. If you don't like the pod2html you have, write your own; it's really easy with Pod::Simple.

Comment: Using C<<>> doesn't help, it still says: "<code>close)", The perldoc command does the right thing with it even when it is "C<openE<40>)>"

Comment: I have Pod::Html version 1.0504 and pod2html seems to just be perl -MPod::Html -e 'pod2html @ARGV' with some POD attached at the beginning.

Comment: No, the C<< >> isn't related to your question. It's just a general statement about nested Pod directives.